# XML:Find particular node in XML using LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, libxml2, xml-libxml

I have an XML file which has only one node called import. I want to find the href attribute of import. I tried using findnodes(), but that returns a list I would have to search further, so I was hoping there was a way to find a particular node which has only one occurence.
I tried getChildrenByTagName but that gives the error

```
Can't locate object method "getChildrenByTagName" via package "XML::LibXML::Document"
```

I also tried grep which gives a similar error

```
Can't locate object method "grep" via package "XML::LibXML::Document"
```

My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource name="data" type="application/dictionary+xml">
<schema>
    <import href="tobefound.xml"/>
</schema>
</resource>
```

My code so far is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $name = $ARGV[1];
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $name);
my @node= $dom->findnodes('//import');
print "List: @node\n";
```

Please let me know if there is a way to find only one particular node without needing to traverse the whole dom and without having to store it as a list. Thank you.

Comment: If you know it's only one node, then just take the first element of `@node`?

Comment: @tinita wouldn't that unnecessarily use a list? Could I just find the first occurrence of `import` in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML doesn't guarantee uniqueness, so any sort of search will return a list of results. This list might be of length 0 or 1, just like with `grep`.

But the easy answer is to just grab the first result:

```
my ($node) = $dom -> findnodes('//import');
```

failing that - specify in your xpath:

```
my ( $node ) = $dom -> findnodes ( '(//import)[1]' );
```

I'm afraid I don't know if that latter will in fact bail out when 'enough' nodes have been selected though.

Comment: Okay, so this was basically typecasting node as a scalar? Sorry, new to perl. Thank you though, worked as needed.

Comment: It's assigning a list result from 'findnodes' to a list on the left hand side. But the list on LHS is one element long, so any other assigments would be discarded. You could write: `my ( $first_match, @rest_of_matches) = ...` and that'll perhaps make it clearer what's going on - we're just discarding `@rest_of_matches`.

Answer (score 1):

`getChildrenByTagName` is a method of Element nodes, not Document nodes.

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $name);
my $root_ele = $doc->documentElement();
my ($import_ele) = $root_ele->getChildrenByTagName('import');
```

You could also use an XPath, though the equivalent XPath would be `import` (searches children), not `//import` (searches descendants).

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $name);
my ($import_ele) = $doc->findnodes('import');
```

This returns all the `import` nodes and keeps the first. But can tell the search to stop looking after finding the first as follows:

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $name);
my ($import_ele) = $doc->findnodes('import[1]');  # Short for 'import[position()=1]'
```